# How can I tell Siri to restart dictation? How can I correct her?

Tags: siri

I know that Siri has "code words" which are not directly transcribed but which insert punctuation.

I find it essential to be able to restart or to go back and clear out words which were dictated improperly.

Is there a way to do this? I have tried saying "Delete", "backspace" and "cancel" and a few more, but they are all (properly) just simply getting dictated.

Comment: http://www.siriuserguide.com/siri-dictation-guide/  (no way to delete)